# D3: multidimensional array of lines

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, svg, d3.js

i want to add a multidimensional array of lines to my SVG with the D3 library. But somehow the lines don´t show up. There is no error message from javascript so i guess i can not be totally wrong but something is missing. I tried to use the description of Mike Bostock as an example http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/

I have an array of lines that looks like that:

```
var datasetPolylines = [[[-10849.0, 1142.0, -10720.0, 454.0],[x1, y1, x2, y2],[x1, y1, x2, y2]...],[polyline],[polyline]...];
```

For every Line there are 4 points in the array for `x` and `y` values of the line.

Now i try to add them to my mainsvg like that:

```
d3.select("#mainsvg").selectAll("g")
                    .data(datasetPolylines) 
                    .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .selectAll("line")
                    .data(function (d) {return d;})
                    .enter()
                    .append("line")
                    .attr("x1", function(d, i) { 
               return xScale(i[0]);
                       })
                .attr("y1", function(d, i) {
               return yScale(i[1]);
                       })
                .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
               return xScale(i[2]);
                     })
                .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
                   return yScale(i[3]);
                     })
                    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                    .attr("stroke", "blue")
                    .attr("fill", "none");
```

I´m very thankful for every hint on where I´m wrong. I´m on this stuff now for some days and just don´t get it :(

Everything works fine if i just draw one polyline with many lines and use the .data attribute just once. I cannot merge the lines to one path also, because they are not always connected and must be drawn seperately.

The complete (and now thanks to Christopher and Lars also working) code example looks like that:

```
var datasetLines = [];
var datasetPolylines = [];

/**Add a line to the dataset for lines*/
function addLineToDataset(x1, y1, x2, y2){
var newNumber1 = x1;    
var newNumber2 = y1;    
 var newNumber3 = x2;
var newNumber4 = y2;
datasetLines.push([newNumber1, newNumber2, newNumber3, newNumber4]);
}

/**Add polyline to the dataset for polylines*/
function addPolyline(){

var polyline = [];

 for (i in datasetLines) {
    polyline[i] = datasetLines[i];
}
datasetPolylines.push(polyline);  
}


/**Draw all polylines from the polylinearray to the svg*/
function showPolylineArray(){

//Create scale functions for x and y axis
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                     .domain([d3.min(outputRange, function(d) { return d[0]; }),  d3.max(outputRange, function(d) { return d[0]; })])//get minimum and maximum of the first entry of the pointarray
                     .range([padding, w - padding]); //w, the SVGs width. without padding 0,w

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                     .domain([d3.min(outputRange, function(d) { return d[1]; }),  d3.max(outputRange, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                     .range([h - padding, padding]); //without padding h,0

d3.select("#mainsvg").selectAll("g")
                    .data(datasetPolylines)
                    .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .selectAll("line")
                    .data(function (d) {return d;})
                    .enter()
                    .append("line")
                    .attr("x1", function(d) {
                          return xScale(d[0]);
                     })
                    .attr("y1", function(d) {
                         return yScale(d[1]);
                     })
                    .attr("x2", function(d) {
                         return xScale(d[2]);
                     })
                    .attr("y2", function(d) {
                        return yScale(d[3]);
                     })
                    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                    .attr("stroke", "blue")
                    .attr("fill", "none")
                    .on('mouseover', function(d){ d3.select(this).style({stroke: 'red'}); })
                    .on('mouseout', function(d){ d3.select(this).style({stroke: 'blue'}); })
                    .append("title")
                    .text("Polyline");

}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `d[0]` rather than `i[0]` etc?

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks, but i tried that and it doesn´t help..

Comment: thanks Christopher, actually that did solve the problem, but i have another problem now, which is that the lines from the array that are drawn are incomplete. I have to call the showPolylineArray-function twice to get all the lines shown on the canvas. Do you have any idea, why not all the data is fetched from the arrays? when i draw each polyline directly after adding it to the array, there is no problem, just when i use the nested example as explained above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost working, except for the referencing of the data (as pointed out by Christopher). You didn't show us the complete code, but the bit you have should work fine with these modifications.

Complete example [here](https://vida.io/documents/d7KbzBGSybaeCs9tD).

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for answering, i tried your proposal, but still i cannot see anything..do i have to change something at the attribute function also? Right now its: .attr("x1", function(d, i) { return xScale(d[0]);  })

Comment: I stand corrected -- I got confused by the brackets. You actually only need two levels. Will update the answer.

Comment: Hi Lars, thank you! Actually it works now, but it shows some weard behaviour, for example if i have only one polyline in the array, it doesn´t show up, just if i have more than one. And also if i have many polylines some are missing. Very strange. Thats why i posted the complete code to my question. Maybe you have an idea whats going on there? I`m not very good in javascript, and i´m calling the functions from my gwt-java-application..

Comment: I get the data from a database, and those are pretty complex long lines.. if you want i can retrieve an example. I figured out that there must be a problem with the timing, that i´m drawing the lines already, when i´m not finished writing them into the arrays or something.. i guess thats why the data is incomplete when i´m drawing it. when i add the same polylines twice, all the data is there. but thanks a lot for your help. i think i´m on the right track now.

Comment: i have also another question: if i want to add the mouseover-colorchanging or other attributes not to every line but to every group of lines, where do i put this statement? Directly after the .append("g") it won´t work..

Comment: I'm guessing that you're not selecting the line elements in your mouse handler. I've updated the example to do that.